# What's the correct 'you' to use in this case?

Tags: translation, second-person-pronouns

Would you leave 'you' out of translating this sentence in a casual conversation with acquaintance by email?

> Money's worth what you make it worth.

So would お金は価値を持ってそれを作るものをの価値がある be correct and still make sense? Or would you have to put in some form of you, like そなた?

> お金は価値を持ってそなたそれを作るものをの価値がある。

Or

> お金は価値を持ってあなたそれを作るものをの価値がある。

Comment: そなた is somewhat comparable to 'thou'. Where did you get the idea it was an ordinary way to say 'you'?

Comment: Regardless of casualness, it depends on whether you intend to say it as a personal advice or a generic remark.

Comment: I have to say neither translations are grammatical

Comment: a generic remark

Answer (score 3):

This type of "you" is called [**generic you**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_you). As you have guessed, how to express generic you depends on the language. In Japanese, it's often best not to specify a subject at all. 人 is a word that can be used to explicitly refer to generic you. あなた/そなた almost never appears in traditional Japanese sayings, but it may be understood in a translated material.

- 欲しいものが常に手に入るわけではない。
  You can't always get what you want.
- 何が起こるか分からない。
  You never know what will happen.
- 人はパンだけで生きるのではない。
  Man shall not live by bread alone.

Your translation attempt has a number of grammatical errors. Most importantly, "to make it worth" cannot be expressed with 作る which only means "to create/establish/make". You have to use a causative form instead. A literal translation would be something like お金には人が価値を持たせる分だけの価値がある, but this still sounds fairly unnatural in Japanese. I recommend rephrasing it like お金の価値は使い方で決まる, 使う人によってお金の価値は変わる, うまく使えば使うほどお金の価値は上がる, etc.